# how to find rows which have specific column value in datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am getting data from sql in datatable which have a column names userid,username and department.I want to get the rows in another datatable by the specific department.
[datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6tjm.png)

I have attached datatable.I just want a datatable which contain the rows which have department "Engineering" from the first datatble

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the DataTable Select method which will return an array of DataRow objects.

```
DataRow[] result = myTable.Select("Department = 'Engineering'");
```

Just replace 'myTable' with your DataTable.

Here is some reference info for the Select method.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Select userid,username,department where department ='Engineering';
```

Do you meant the above?

Comment: no i dont want to use another sql query. i have only datatable and want to get another table whaich have rows having department Engineering ...Thanks